# Generate DITA files from the file names in an Excel sheet

Tags: xml, dita

I work as Information Developer.

I need to create **.dita** files with the file names stored in an excel sheet.

The .dita files are XML files. The structure of the files should be same. The structure is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2011, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN"
"concept.dtd">
<?Pub Inc?>
<concept id="concept-1-43B80068" xml:lang="en">
<title></title><?Pub Caret -1?>
<shortdesc></shortdesc>
<conbody>
<p></p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

and then I need to create a map of these files as follows:

```
<map xml:lang="en">
<topicref href = "topic1.dita">
<topicref href = "topic2.dita">
</topicref>
</map>
```

Please provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know how to program in Python and run Python apps, you can try the following where you put your file names in a list. If you need to read from Excel, then you can use one of the packages for reading Excel files in Python and use that in place of filelist below.

```
import os

filelist = ["topic1",
"topic2"
]    # array of dita files

basedir = r'C:/DITA_files/'

# create files
if not os.path.exists(basedir):
    os.mkdir(basedir) 

conceptstr = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN"
"concept.dtd">
<?Pub Inc?>
<concept id="concept-1-%s" xml:lang="en">
<title></title><?Pub Caret -1?>
<shortdesc></shortdesc>
<conbody>
<p></p>
</conbody>
</concept>
'''

id_len = 8
# create concept files and map
for file in filelist:
    print 'Writing ' + basedir + file + '.dita'
    cf = open(basedir + file +'.dita', 'w')
    cf.write(conceptstr) % [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in xrange(id_len)]
    cf.close()

map = open(basedir + 'mymap.ditamap','wt')

map.write('<map xml:lang="en">')
for file in filelist:
    map.write(r'''<topicref href="%s.dita"/>
''' % ( register, register ) )
    map.write('</map>')
    map.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can create a VBA macro for it in Excel. Select the cell with the filename in it and run the macro.
Attention: To get double quotes in the output you need to put them twice as ""

```
Sub CreateDitaConcept()
Dim sFileName As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

'Read filename from selected cell
sFileName = Selection.Value
'Get a free file number
iFileNum = FreeFile
'Open the file for output
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
'Print text to the file
Print #iFileNum, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
Print #iFileNum, "<!-- Arbortext etc -->"
Print #iFileNum, "<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC ""-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN"" ""concept.dtd"">"
Print #iFileNum, "<concept id=""concept_id"" xml:lang=""en"">"
Print #iFileNum, "<title>Concept title</title>"
Print #iFileNum, "<shortdesc></shortdesc>"
Print #iFileNum, "<conbody>"
Print #iFileNum, "<p>paragraph</p>"
Print #iFileNum, "</conbody>"
Print #iFileNum, "</concept>"
'Close file
Close #iFileNum
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Do note that your DITA markup is invalid. All DITA topics must have a `<title>` element that contains content. You might want to add some placeholder text as content of the `<title>` element, for example:

```
<title>Title goes here</title>
```

Also, you do not need the below markup, as these are processing instructions added by PTC's Arbortext Editor:

```
<?Pub Inc?>
<?Pub Caret -1?>
```